# "Dates" set as General, should be set to DATES

Tags: excel, vba

I have my VBA script working correctly, however, I do not understand why the dates on column "C" are set and changed to "General" when they should remain as Dates. If my dates do not land on Sheet2 as Dates then formula on column "E" will not display Days Outstanding as sheet should display with formulas.

VBA Script below:

```
Sub deleteRowswithSelectedText4()

Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim szRange As String
Dim rng As Range

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") = "LLC" Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i


szRange = "A118:D300"

             Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A16:B300,J16:J300,R16:R300").Copy_ 
             Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A118:D300")


Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C118:C300").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the last line in your macro not changing it back to `m/d/yyyy`?

Comment: @ dwirony, Correct, macro not changing back to m/d/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Copy Method get the Format of the Text

U could use .value2 (Who do not change the formats)

also .value2 is much faster then Copy

```
 With Worksheet("Sheet2")
    .Range("A16:B300").value2 = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A118:B300").value2
    .Range("J16:J300").valu2 = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("C118:C300").value2
    .Range("R16:R300") = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("D118:D300").value2
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

When a date comes over as a string, a quick fix is to use `TextToColumns` similar to:

```
Columns("A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
```

This will typically set the date to your local (computer) settings.

Comment: Sheet1 is set to "General", after copy paste into Sheet2, it remains set as General not Date.    There is no way for me to change Sheet1 to "Date".

Comment: @Robert-Macro what is the issue running this with sheet 2?